# Did cunnilingus actually happen in Basic Instinct?

Tags: film-techniques, basic-instinct

In [Basic Instinct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Instinct), it seemed to me that rather using awkward props or various ways to fake it, it would have been logistically simpler if cunnilingus had actually taken place between Michael Douglas and Sharon Stone. Plus, it's not full penetrative sex and the actors' emotions and reactions would have been authentic. Can we know this for sure one way or another?

Comment: [Considering Douglas blames oral sex](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/oral-sex-and-throat-cancer-michael-douglas-hpv-report-spotlights-epidemic/) for his tongue cancer, it may be interesting to stay tuned....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it did not.  In fact, both actors (there were no body doubles) has stipulations in their contract as to what they would and wouldn't do, and the actors wore padding over their genitalia due to the (then recently front-and-center) AIDS scare running through Hollywood.

Regarding those stipulations, it was agreed that Michael Douglas would not go full frontal in the film, or to let his character be bisexual.

Source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103772/trivia)

Comment: Bah reality can be so boring!

Comment: @pacoverflow Hey, if you propose an alternative answer, I'll be very interested in seeing it. For Johnny's answer, I do see the claim about the pads, nonetheless the claims in the link list no sources so I wasn't 100% happy.